# Making cronjob from AppleScript

Tags: cron, applescript

I am trying make a `crontab` run an apple script.
My problem is the script doesn't seem to run. i dont get any error messages or anything the script just doesn't run.

The my apple script just opens the mac calculator. As follows:

```
tell application "System Events"
get name of every process whose name is "Calculator"
if result is not {} then
    tell application "Calculator"
        quit
        end tell
    else
    tell application "Calculator"
        activate
        end tell
    end if
```

end tell

This script runs fine and opens the calculator no problem when I click run button in the script editor window.
I saved this file as `calculator_script` on my desktop, it is a `.scpt` file.

To run the cronjob i open terminal and type:

1. `crontab -e`
2. `i`
3. `23 16 * * * cd Desktop && calculator_script.scpt`
4. press esc
5. `:wq`

it says a new cronjob is created but but when the time comes that i specified in the cronjob expression nothing happens.

I can't see where I've gone wrong.
I know the script works because it opens the calculator, so it must be something to do with the cronjob. I make sure that I put the time a couple of minutes into the future in the cronjob expression.

When type `crontab -l` i see my cronjob in the list. it just never runs for some reason.

Comment: You do not need to overcomplicate the _code_ using **System Events**. Have a look at this _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ as it does what you want in a straight forward manner: https://paste.ee/p/9TtrW

Answer (score 0):

- iactually i solved it, i needed to use osascript to run the script. so it ended up being:
  `59 16 * * * cd desktop && osascript calculator_script.scpt`